# PowerShell / Azure VM - Move preferred language to the top of the list

Tags: powershell, azure

I have an issue where my date time format on my Azure VM changes to this:

```
mm/dd/yyyy
```

If I move the language English (Australia) to the top of the list, the date time format changes to this:

```
dd/mm/yyyy
```

which is what I want.

[image]

I really need to do this in PowerShell so it is automated.

Comment: Please stop signing your posts "Russ". Your posts are already signed with your user card.

Comment: @meagar Why? Maybe I just like doing that.

Comment: Because it is explicitly against the rules: http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you have logged in and just want to change timezone on this VM, you could use [Script to change the time zone in Windows 7 or Windows 8 (PowerShell)](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Script-to-change-the-time-f8f86cb4)
2. If you want to change timezone when creating new Azure VM, you could add a new AzureVMConfig by using [Add-AzureProvisioningConfig](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495299.aspx), in which you could set your TimeZone as parameter, for example:

   ```
   New-AzureVMConfig -Name "DomainVM" -InstanceSize Small -ImageName $img ` | Add-AzureProvisioningConfig -Windows –Password $Password -TimeZone <your time zone> ` | New-AzureVM -ServiceName $serviceName
   ```